# Leaflet prevents window from scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet, parallax

I am creating a website in some kind of parallax design and for some sections I need map as background. I want the map to be insensitive to mouse wheel scrolling, but I want to keep the +- buttons zoom control. But my solution still does not work - once I scroll to the map and click on it I am not able to scroll away from it anymore. Here is the fiddle with my current setup:

https://jsfiddle.net/Drozi/x7jg4we6/47/

```
If you try to scroll down to the map, click on the map, you cant scroll back after that.
```

I tried to build a fiddle from scratch and after that it worked. Unfortunately the same setup (I am definitely missing something here) does not work within the entire webpage (and also in the shared fiddle).

I use Bootstrap4.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see your problem in the jsfiddle. Adding `pointer-events: none` to the leaflet map container seemed to fix it for me.  Even after clicking on the map, the page still scrolls with your parallax effect, and the zoom control still works:

```css
#leafletmap-places {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 0;
    pointer-events: none; // <--- works for me
}
```

[Here's your fiddle forked with the change](https://jsfiddle.net/slutske/b7cfu29p/1/), Let me know if that works for you.

(I'm not sure if this was your intention, but your map was not responding to drag events - this continues to be true with my change.  However my change also disables double-click events.  If you map needs more interactivity, there is probably more tweaking that needs to be done.)

Comment: This is not the case as I already have this setting applied. The issue is not about preventing the map from zooming but the map prevents the window from scrolling.

Comment: Oops you're correct, I took another look and changed my answer